# Superposition: where did I get it wrong?

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, superposition

[image]

I'm using superposition to solve this circuit, but I get the wrong answer. Can anyone tell me why?

1. With regards to V1 I get U_a = 35 V and U_b = 21.6 V
2. With regards to V2 I get U_a = -5.44 V and U_b = -12.6 V
3. With regards to I1 I get U_a = 10.9 V and U_b = 25.5 V

Comment: Do each superposition state in here: https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html

Comment: Show us **all** of your work.

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend going through the process of re-drawing your schematics ***before*** analysis. And don't bus ground around. Just mark it. In fact, do the same for voltage supplies, too. Just mark them. Saves lots of trouble and gets rid of wiring that will only serve to distract you.

So, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq1ho9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From the above, I think you need to look more closely at what you did for the first one, \$V_1\$. The other two are close enough for horse shoes, though I get slightly different results for the second case, \$V_2\$. The big error appears to be the first one, though.